# how to get day format from new Date in Angularjs

Tags: javascript

i want to get the value of the day format from new Date()(current date) in my angularjs projet. I try this code in my javascript file:

```
 var today = (new Date()).toISOString(); 
 console.log(today.getDay());
```

when running my code, i get this message error :

```
TypeError: today.getDay is not a function
```

however there are many solutions with this syntax. 
How can i fix it please. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getDay` on the `Date` object not on the ISO string:

```
var today = (new Date()).getDay();
```

`getDay` returns a value from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday).

Comment: But when i try to use the same function with a date that i get it from my database (is formatted with toISOString) , the same error is displayed .

Comment: toISOString converts it into a string and it no longer remains a Date object. You can use getDay() only on a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want current date and day according to your timezone then ->

```
var today = new Date().getDay() // 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday).
var currentDate = new Date().getDate()
```

If you want current date and day according to UTC timezone then ->

```
var today = new Date().getUTCDay() // 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday).
var currentDate = new Date().getUTCDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get date by using below code

```
 let dayno = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() ,20).getDay();<br>
```

if date is 20-11-2019 then Day No is :3